# Positioning of the relative sized table-cell element (IE bug?)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I'm getting little desperate here. I have this page with the contain sized background images and since it's responsive design, there are relatively sized and positioned bubbles around the layout containing images and headings (try to resize the browser window to see why is everything positioned and sized that way). Image is visible by default, heading is visible on hover/touch. Headings should be centered vertically and horizontally, that's why I am using display table on the parent element and display table-cell on the heading itself. The problem is that the IE (9 to 11) reproduces the heading next to the parent, height is a-ok; the width however, is not. Every other browser works fine. I am out of ideas how to fix this and my knowledge of browser behavior is obviously not such vast as yours. Any clues how to fix this?

Live code can be found here: **http://klient.triakis.cz/sa/products.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like IE interprets the image as the first cell column, thus pushing the label to the right as a second column.

Seems to work if you give the img absolute position:

```
.products li a img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```